# Add ModelStateError without ViewModelClass.ModelClass annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

I have created a special viewmodel class for my model, for adding data that is to be computed into the model, like some int for time

```
public class SessionView
{
    public Session Session { get; set; }
    public int StartHour { get; set; }
    public int StartMin { get; set; }
    public int EndHour { get; set; }
    public int EndMin { get; set; }
}
```

When i do my validation with custom validators, i add the errors to the ModelState without the ".Session" needed by the view to find the right place to add the error on postback.

How do i do to be able to display the error, by adding it as `ModelState.AddModelError("Name","error")` instead of `ModelState.AddModelError("Session.Name","error")`?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear at all. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this is not possible. If inside the view you have the following fields:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Session.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Session.Name)
```

then its corresponding `ModelState` key is `Session.Name` and that's what you should use if you want to associate it an error message.

But in order to avoid those problems you could use Data Annotation or write custom validation attributes and then decorate the corresponding properties with those attributes. This way you don't need to worry about the keys because things might get even uglier if you are working for example with collections - `Sessions[3].Name`.

As an alternative to Data Annotations you may checkout [FluentValidation.Net](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).